# How could i show video stream in larger view after clicking on smaller view using webrtc

Tags: javascript

How could i show video stream in larger view after clicking on smaller view using webrtc .If somebody has the code , please share it. Basically i have to maximize one video stream in all the video after clicking on it.I tried webrtc functions but it is not solved.

Comment: Post Your Code.

Answer (score 0):

The magic of CSS. Assuming your video element is accessible as "video" to JavaScript try this:

```
video.onclick = function () {
    video.style.width = video.videoWidth + 'px';
    video.style.height = video.videoHeight + 'px';
};
```